# Printf Statement Runs After Function Goes From 'Void' to 'Int'

Tags: arrays, c

I'm new to C.

I've made some code which creates an array, allows for user input to initialise the indexes of the array, and finally the inputs are checked against some parameters.

When I was originally testing the code, the function which contained the verification process was a 'void' function, but since I want this verification function to be the gatekeeper as to whether other functions run in my program, I changed it to an 'int' function so it could return a value which determined whether or not the rest of the program would run.

However, now it returns the printf statement in about invalid inputs twice. When it was a void function it would only display it once. How do I only get the printf statement in 'int verify' to display once?

**Expected Input & Output:**

1 2 1 3 4 5 **} Input**

Invalid input: 6 integers 1..9 in sorted order must be supplied. **} Output**

---

**Current Output:**

1 2 1 3 4 5                       **} Input**

Invalid input: 6 integers 1..9 in sorted order must be supplied.**}**

Invalid input: 6 integers 1..9 in sorted order must be supplied.**} Output**

```
#define SIZE 6                     //Size of array                    

void input(int selection[SIZE]);
int verify(int selection[SIZE]);

int main (void){
    int selection[SIZE] = {0};
    input(selection);
    verify(selection);
    if (verify(selection) == 1) {
        printf("Correct!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

//Function which assigns user input into array 
void input(int selection[SIZE]){
    int i = 0;
    while (i < SIZE) {
        scanf("%d", &selection[i]);
        i++;
    }
} 
  
//Function to verify that user's input stays within the bounds
int verify(int selection[SIZE]){
    int ver1 = 0;
    int ver2 = 0;
    int para = 1;
    
    //Checks if inputted numbers are in desired range.
      while (ver1 < SIZE) {
        if (selection[ver1] > 9 || selection[ver1] < 1) {
            printf("Invalid input: 6 integers 1..9 ");
            printf("in sorted order must be supplied.\n");        
            ver2 = SIZE;  //Prevents other checks from running as to have duplicate text
            ver1 = SIZE;  //Prevents other checks from running as to have duplicate text
            para = 0;
        }  
        ver1++;    
     }
      
    //Loops through each value inputed into the function and verifies that
    //they are in sorted order   
    while (ver2 < (SIZE-1)) {
        if (selection[ver2] > selection[ver2+1]){
            printf("Invalid input: 6 integers 1..9"); 
            printf(" in sorted order must be supplied.\n");
            ver2 = SIZE;
            para = 0;
        }
    ver2++;
    }
    return para;  
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: If you mean this line `if (verify(selection) == 1)`, it only makes sense if the function has type `int`.

Comment: @Eras please show an example of input and expected vs. actual output. [Edit] your question.

Comment: In the future, try to remove everything that is not important to the question. For example, is the while at the bottom important to this question? Not really. Then you should not make SO users read it. Try to create a minimal example that only demonstrates the problem that you have.

Comment: You are calling `verify` twice, once before the `if` and once within the `if` control expression. Simply delete the first call.

Comment: I'm completely unsure what is wrong so I've just attached the code that is causing the problem

Comment: @Eras please format the input/output section you added properly so it is readable

Answer (score 3):

Change this code:

```
    verify(selection);
    if (verify(selection) == 1) {
        printf("Correct!\n");
    }
```

to this:

```
    if (verify(selection) == 1) {
        printf("Correct!\n");
    }
```

Basically, `verify` was producing output twice because you were calling it twice.

Answer (score 2):

Your code was calling verify twice, causing 'invalid input' to be printed twice.

You called it once before the if, and once inside the if.

If you want to check what the verify function returned, without calling it again, you can write something like this:

```
int checkResult = verify(selection);
if ( checkResult == 1) {
    printf("Correct!\n");
```

Comment: So the way the code is setup now recalls the 'verify' function in the 'if' statement?

Comment: That is an awkward phrasing. The result of the function is stored in the variable. There is no need to call the function again to see what the result was.

Comment: BTW here is how you find out what is pertinent to your question and what is not: You remove everything from the verify function and leave just a 'printf' and a 'return 1.'  Is the printf still executed twice? If so, the rest of the code, while, etc is not relevant to the question.

Comment: _So the way the code is setup now recalls the 'verify' function in the 'if' statement?_: yes, it's called once here: `verify(selection);` and it's called a second time here: `if (verify(selection) == 1) ...`. When you call a function, you call a function, regardless if the call occurs on it's own, during an assignment, in an `if` condition or anywhere else.